# Non-blocking bash command

Tags: bash, job-control

Let's say I have a bash script with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
gedit
rm *.temp
```

When I execute it using `sh ./test.sh`, `gedit` pops-up but the `rm` part does not run until after I close `gedit`.

I want the script to continue running even if `gedit` isn't closed; like the `gedit` isn't blocking the bash execution.

<sub>The example I gave is just an example (putting the `rm` first won't work in a real situation).</sub>

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The term you are looking for is called "backgrounding" a job. When you run a command either in your shell or in a script you can add a flag at the end to send it to the background and continue running new commands or the rest of the script. In most shells including `sh`, this is the `&` character.

```
#!/bin/sh
gedit &
rm ./*.temp
```

That way, the shell doesn't wait for the termination of `gedit` and both `rm` and `gedit` will run concurrently.

The term "blocking" usually has to do with input/output streams, often to files or a device. It's also used in compiled languages in something similar to the sense you used, but in bash and similar shell scripting, the terminology (and function!) is rather different.

Comment: thank you!  that explain why I was only getting fifo and input results on google :D

Comment: My impression is, that Plante wants to influence a script from outside, to perform each operation in background, not to rewrite the script.

Comment: @user: It took me a couple reads to even guess what he wanted. Maybe you could comment on the question for clarification.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks again. works great so far!

Answer (score 1):

This will not produce any output whatsoever. It will also detach from the Terminal and won't block anything:

```bsh
nohup gedit >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```